# My Laars mighty therm won't keep a flame

Tags: lighting, boiler, thermocouple

I have a Laars mighty therm when I press the button to lite the pilot flame is on when I release it doesn't stay lit changed thermocouple  twice heated the coupler for a while still nothing

Comment: Probably not the thermocouple.  What is the pilot flame like when on?  Is it nice and blue and steady?  Might be a dirty flame sensor.

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:lighting], if you hover over the tag, the text reads that it's about providing artificial light, not about igniting a burner. Since I'm not familiar with what a "Laars mighty term" is, exactly I presume that's _not_ what you mean, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Please clarify what type of device you are trying to operate (make/model) and PLEASE add some punctuation to your post.

Comment: The name is associated with both water heaters and boilers, so yeah, details definitely needed. https://www.laars.com/products/mighty-therm Please [edit] some details into your question